# Spring facet not working, intellij

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

I had a project which worked, and then suddenly stopped. Spring was failing to inject

```
@Configuration
@Order(2)
public static class RegularSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private Environment env;

    @Inject
    private AjaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
        //Could not autowire. No bean of name 'ajaxAuth..' type found
...
```

the `AjaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler` class looks like this

```
@Component
public class AjaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
...
```

I discovered that the facet was configured, but the line where the file with the `main` method as well as `@ComponentScan` was red.

[image]

Is this related to my problem? How do inform Spring of the `ajaxAuth..` class? Even when I switch to a previously working branch, this happens.

Here is `Application.java`:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.class, MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    @Inject
    private Environment env;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initApplication() {
        if (env.getActiveProfiles().length == 0) {
            log.warn("No Spring profile configured, running with default configuration");
        } else {
            log.info("Running with Spring profile(s) : {}", Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Main method, used to run the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        if (Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES") <= 128) {
            log.error("You need Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) to run the system");
            return;
        }

        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        System.setProperty("user.timezone", "UTC");
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.setShowBanner(false);

        SimpleCommandLinePropertySource source = new SimpleCommandLinePropertySource(args);

        // Check if the selected profile has been set as argument.
        // if not the development profile will be added
        addDefaultProfile(app, source);
        addLiquibaseScanPackages();
        Environment env = app.run(args).getEnvironment();
//      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", env.getProperty("server.ssl.key-store"));
//      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", env.getProperty("server.ssl.key-store-password"));

        String httpPort = env.getProperty("httpPort");
        String httpsPort = env.getProperty("server.port");

        String div = "----------------------------------------------------------";
        String local = "\tLocal: \t\thttps://127.0.0.1:" + httpsPort;
        String external = "\tExternal: \thttps://" + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() + ":" + httpsPort;

        if (httpPort != null) {
            div += "-----------------------------";
            local += " & http://127.0.0.1:" + httpPort;
            external += " & http://" + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() + ":" + httpPort;
        }

        log.info("Access URLs:\n" + div + "\n" + local + "\n" + external + "\n" + div);
    }

    /**
     * Set a default profile if it has not been set
     */
    private static void addDefaultProfile(SpringApplication app, SimpleCommandLinePropertySource source) {
        if (!source.containsProperty("spring.profiles.active")) {
            app.setAdditionalProfiles(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the liquibases.scan.packages to avoid an exception from ServiceLocator.
     */
    private static void addLiquibaseScanPackages() {
        System.setProperty("liquibase.scan.packages", Joiner.on(",").join(
            "liquibase.change", "liquibase.database", "liquibase.parser",
            "liquibase.precondition", "liquibase.datatype",
            "liquibase.serializer", "liquibase.sqlgenerator", "liquibase.executor",
            "liquibase.snapshot", "liquibase.logging", "liquibase.diff",
            "liquibase.structure", "liquibase.structurecompare", "liquibase.lockservice",
            "liquibase.ext", "liquibase.changelog"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a JHipster-generated Spring Boot application class until I added a `@Configuration` annotation to the class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.class, 
MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application {
    /* ... */
}
```

The three annotations alternatively could be replaced with a single `@SpringBootApplication` annotation:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.class, 
MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application {
    /* ... */
}
```

Both appear to work with IDEA 2017.1.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a problem resolving your main class `Application.java`. Simply try to remove and re-add the Spring facet (you'll need to recreate manual contexts additionally).

Comment: I've tried this. I end up at the same place i was before :/

Comment: Is Application class public? Do you have any unresolved classpath entries? Did you try to reimport via Maven/Gradle? Eventually corrupted caches of JARs?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by reimport via Maven. Intellij lets you click on a 'bean' next to `@ComponentScan` by the line numbers, I'm guessing this is all the beans it handles. In there is the class `ajaxAuth..java`, so it is aware of it. I'm not sure why its not being injected if it is aware of it.

Comment: The first and foremost problem is why Application.java is highlighted in red. Unless the main Spring Boot configuration is not resolved properly, no other Spring functionality can be expected to work. Please double-check the Application class for any errors and eventually missing "public" in class definition.

Comment: I've added `Application.java` to the post, it looks pretty normal to me. It is the same in the master branch too, so maybe this has to do with intellij rather than the code?

Comment: Thanks, indeed it looks OK. It would be easier to follow up on our issue tracker if you can provide the full project as ZIP https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA (you can set visibility of issue to "idea-developers" to hide it from public). Thanks.